# Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.cxf.resource.ResourceManager'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jetty

When I try to run the java application with Jetty in eclipse. I'm getting this error:

`SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.cxf.resource.ResourceManager' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [com.unitedhealthgroup.clinical.framework.commonj.MockWorkManager] for bean with name 'dbMockWorkManager' defined in class path resource [spring/eligibility-cache.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: commonj/work/WorkManager`

Comment: you need commonj jar in your classpath or maven dependencies.

Comment: please add aditional information about your project like pom.xml, dependencies spring context etc....